# How can you use NPM and Gulp for front end JS

Tags: javascript, npm

I have noticed recently that some front end JS libraries are no longer putting themselves in Bower repositories and instead only putting themselves in NPM repositories.

If I were to use NPM to install these front end libraries, they would end up in the node_modules folder, the same place that all of the "backend" node.js modules are.

Given that I am using GULP currently to look in bower-components directory and basically get all of the files, how could I then specify to gulp that I also want to include some but not all of the things in the node_modules folder?

And yes I know I could manually list each file to Gulp with a path to node_modules, that isn't the answer I am looking for.

Comment: Use webpack or browserify

Comment: I recommend you use webpack to resolve you problem. Look [here](https://github.com/wwwebman/gulp-webpack-starter/blob/master/tasks/helpers/webpackConfig.js) on line 40. You can define custom folder that can be resolved (./node_modules or ./any_custom_folder) and so on... Then you just require you lib like [here](https://github.com/wwwebman/gulp-webpack-starter/blob/master/dev/js/main.js) on line 6.

Comment: Thanks both. I guess that's the life of a Javascript developer... forget anything you knew last year and learn something new! :)